# How to export .csv with Django-Tables2?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-tables2

I'm trying to export a table in .csv with Django-Tables2, I've done the following so far.

**tables.py**

```py
class ClientTable(ColumnShiftTable):

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        sequence = ('id', 'nome_razao_social', 'cpf', 'cnpj', 'sit_fiscal')
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html'
```

**views.py**

```py
class ClientsView(ExportMixin, CustomListView):
    template_name = 'relatorios/clients/geral.html'
    model = Client
    table_class = ClientTable
    context_object_name = 'all_clients'
    permission_codename = 'view_clients'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(RelatorioClientsView,
                        self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        table = ClientTable(Client.objects.all())
        table.paginate(page=self.request.GET.get('page', 1), per_page=15)

        context['table'] = table
        RequestConfig(self.request).configure(table)

        export_format = self.request.GET.get('_export', None)
        if TableExport.is_valid_format(export_format):
            exporter = TableExport(export_format, table)
            return exporter.response('table.{}'.format(export_format))

        return context
```

**template.html**

```html
<div class="tabel" style="overflow-x: auto; white-space: nowrap;">
    {% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
    {% render_table table %}

    {% export_url "csv" %}
</div>
```

But I get this error `Invalid block tag on line 56: 'export_url', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?`

if I remove `{% export_url "csv" %}` the error stops appearing, but I do not have the link.

Comment: Is export_url the name of the url?  If so, you need `{% url 'export_url' csv %}`.  If not, you need to load the relevant templatetags file `{% load name-of-templatetags-file %}`

Comment: I did according to documentation.
"You can use the querystring template tag included with django_tables2 to render a link to export the data as csv:

`{% export_url "csv"%}`
This will make sure any other query string parameters will be preserved, for example in combination when filtering table items." @HenryM

Comment: Did you include `{% load django_tables2 %}` at the top of your template?

Comment: @HenryM - When I add `{% load django_tables2 %}` I get this error `ClientsView' object has no attribute 'get_table'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `template.html` I added `{% load django_tables2%}`

I passed `SingleTableMixin` as the 'ClientsView' parameter.

In `ClientTable` I added `export_formats = ['csv', 'xlsx']`

This solved my problem.